# Creation a set of string from a string of 0's and 1's,where only two characters are changed(python)

Tags: python, string

Suppose i have the following string: `'0000'`

I want to create a set of strings, where only two numbers are changed(from 0 to 1 in this case)

For example from a string `'0000'` i will get a result: `{'0011', '0101', '0110', '1001', '1010', '1100'}`

Here is my code:

```
def shift_two(string):
  shift_2 = set()
  for i in range(len(string)):
    if i == len(string) - 1:
      break

    str_temp = list(string)
    if str_temp[i] == '1':
      str_temp[i] = '0'
    else:
      str_temp[i] = '1'

    #copy a string, because list is mutable
    for j in range(i+1,len(string)):
      copy_str = str_temp.copy()

      if copy_str[j] == '1':
        copy_str[j] = '0'
        shift_2.add(''.join(copy_str))
      else:
        copy_str[j] = '1'
        shift_2.add(''.join(copy_str))

  return shift_2
```

But maybe there is more efficient ways(and more readable) to complete this task?

Comment: If your code works but you want to improve it, it may be a better candidate for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a more readable (and probably also more efficient) solution to your problem:

```
def flip(letter):
    if letter == '0':
        return '1'
    elif letter == '1':
        return '0'

def shift_two(string):
    permutations = []

    for ind_1 in range(len(string)):
        for ind_2 in range(ind_1+1, len(string)):
            string_list = list(string)
            string_list[ind_1] = flip(string[ind_1])
            string_list[ind_2] = flip(string[ind_2])

            permutations.append(string_list)

    return permutations
```

and

```
string = '0000'
shift_two(string)
```

returns a list of all the desired permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution I wrote using recursion. It can probably be made slightly better, but it's an improvement.

```
def shift_two(string, index, shiftSet):
    string = list(string)
    if (string.count('1') < 2 and index < len(string)):
        shift_two("".join(string), index + 1, shiftSet)
        string[index] = "1"
        shift_two("".join(string), index + 1, shiftSet)
    else:
        if (string.count('1') == 2):
            shiftSet.add("".join(string))

shiftSet = set()
shift_two("0000", 0, shiftSet)
print(shiftSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant that uses [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools - Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import itertools as it


def replace(s, replacements):
    if len(s) < len(replacements):
        return s
    base = s[:-len(replacements)] + "".join(replacements)
    return sorted(set("".join(i) for i in it.permutations(base, len(base))))


def main(*argv):
    s = "0000"
    repls = ("1", "1")
    l = list(replace(s, repls))
    print(l)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061258915]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> ['0011', '0101', '0110', '1001', '1010', '1100']
>
> Done.
> ```